# Suggestions Please: File in Xcode Project but Cannot be Found

Tags: xcode, appcode

I have a file that shows up in "Open Quickly" on Xcode and shows up no place in the project if I do "Reveal in Project Navigator".  It does compile correctly into several targets.

If I add the file to the project, the project cannot compile because the file is already included. How can I find this inclusion?

Note: The file does NOT show up in "Open Quickly" on App Code, but I can navigate to it via Command-B.

Comment: did you try to remove and add it again?

Comment: @Will it's not in the project, so removing it is impossible. It cannot be found in the project navigator whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bizarre situation happens because you are importing a .m file in one of your `#import` statements. If you fix this, the project will no longer compile, because the file will not be automatically included.

Answer (score 4):

In AppCode you can use `Navigate | File... (Cmd+Shift+O)` and check `Include non-project files` - the file should be shown in the list.
Also, you can open the file in editor, switch navigator to `Files` mode and use `Navigate | Select in... (Alt+F1) | Project View` - the file will be shown in its actual location.
After that use `Manager Targets` action from context menu to see what targets this file belong to.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to delete this question if I can, since I no longer have the situation to test with ;)

Comment: Could not delete. Anyway, I tried to select it in project view, but it was nowhere to be found, even in App Code.